# How can I print to multiple printers with javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I select one of the connected printers before printing in javascript?
When we print directly with window.print()
I take the default printer.
I need to print to different printers located in different areas of my business,
Example:

1. Kitchen -> printer 1
2. var printer 2

[image]

window.print()
To print without confirmation, the default printer is used; It does not allow you to indicate the name of the printer through which you want to print.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+print+to+specific+printer+site:stackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)